# does it necessary using constant for database information(php)?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to know what is the following ways are better programming way and why  :
1-just use a one file for connection :

> connection.php:

```
<?php
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$connection)
{
die("data base connection faild:".mysql_error());
}
$db=mysql_select_db("widget_corp");
if(!$db)
{
die("not db selection".mysql_error());
}
?>
```

2- use a file for connection and an other to store db access information:

> connection.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'constants.php';
$connection=mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);  
if(!$connection)
{
die("data base connection faild:".mysql_error());
}
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
if(!$db)
{
die("not db selection".mysql_error());
}
?>
```

> constans.php

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS','');
define('DB_NAME','widget_corp');
?>
```

Comment: In general most frameworks use a single config file that stores your constants such as your database connection information.  This makes it easier to update this information because it is located in one file instead of split between each class or module you are building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer use this method

```
return array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
);
```

and then

```
$config = include 'config.php';
$connection=mysql_connect($config['host'],['username'],$config['password']);
```